# What's the deal with [android-version]?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm cleaning up the thirty-odd questions with the [android-version](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-version) tag. I can't see what the tag is really used for. Primarily, lately, it just looks to be what people choose because [android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android) is blacklisted.

Can anybody come up with a good use for this tag? There's certainly nothing in the tag wiki for it.

***Update***: Okay, these are all cleaned up now. For the most part I replaced it with an actual version tag or, more often, simply removed it since it was superfluous. In some cases it was replaced with [android-versions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-versions), for which I need to write a tag-wiki.

Comment: It doesn't sound useful to me. It should be replaced with the actual android version in regards to the question, right?

Comment: In most cases, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first three questions kind of use it sensibly:

- https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/290/why-arent-the-manufacturers-updating-the-phone-to-the-latest-android-version-whe
- [What is a "Froyo"?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1629/what-is-a-froyo)
- [What percentage of devices have each of the Android versions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4447/what-percentage-of-users-use-each-of-the-android-versions)

Those are clearly questions about different versions of Android in a general sense.

That said, I don't think the tag is useful, and it's certainly been abused.  It doesn't create a useful category; I don't think filtering for these questions would be a common behavior.

Comment: And, for those, I think [tag:android-versions] is better. A small change, but it makes more sense to me.

Comment: @Al I would agree.